# Why :checked class not working in nested ul li. Try to display content div using checked class

Tags: html, css

I try to show and hide content using :checked class but it looks like not working in nested UL LI list. Any one guide me to solve this please. Look like I made some mistake which I am not able to see.

```css
div#content {
    display:none;
}

#show:checked ~ div#content{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<input type=radio id="show" name="group">
<label for="show">Show</label>
</li>

<li>
<input type=radio id="show1" name="group">
<label for="show1">Show</label>
</li>

<li>
<input type=radio id="show2" name="group">
<label for="show2">Show</label>

<li>
<input type=radio id="show3" name="group">
<label for="show3">Show</label>
</li>

<li>
<input type=radio id="show4" name="group">
<label for="show4">Show</label>
</li>

<li>
<input type=radio id="show5" name="group">
<label for="show5">Show</label>
</li>
</ul>


<div id="content">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#content {
display: none;
}

.show:checked ~ #content {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="show" id="show1" class="show">
<label for="show1">Show</label>

<input type="radio" name="show" id="show2" class="hide">
<label for="show2">Hide</label>

<div id="content">Contents here</div>
```

The `~` selector only targets sibling-level elements. Since your `:checked` input is nested, it's not actually siblings with the `#content` div. The `ul` and the `div` are siblings. The `input` and its `label` are siblings. And one `li` is a sibling with the next `li`. But to get from the `input` to the `div#content`, you have to go up a few levels in the dom. Thus, not siblings.

You'll have to either change how your markup is set up (see the snippet below for an example; I added the "hide" box just to make it easier to see the effect, but the important part is that the input and the div are siblings), or change how you're handling the hide/show behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Working fine now.